# Java EE run error "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${client.url}"

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I have an Enterprise Java Application. Which has a *.war and a *.jar, when I ran the war it works fine but when I run the Enterprise shows me an error "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${client.url}"

When I clean and build it's all ok but when I run it I'm having the following error at the Netbeans' console:
[image]
I'm using: Netbeans 8.1, wildfly 10.0, Java EE 7
And this is my tree...

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I was with the same problem and I fell on this question. Just solve.
To resolve the error project.properties open the file within the folder nbproject.

Inside this file insert a line below client.urlPart with the following content:

client.url=http://localhost:8080/${client.urlPart}

Change the port number (8080) to the port number of your server.

Regards.